# Where's commit and rollback buttons in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server

In Toad for Oracle, there are handy commit and rollback buttons in the IDE

In SQL Server Management Studio (with auto commit off), are those buttons available in any of the toolbars?

Comment: No, SSMS does not have built-in buttons for this. Besides, you should have scripts that include BEGIN TRANSACTION / COMMIT / ROLLBACK instead of relying on UI buttons. IMHO.

Comment: Wow, what an easy way to lock up my whole database!

Comment: So...the leading IDE for Oracle (Toad) has commit/rollback buttons that everybody uses, and SMMS can have autocommit turned off but Microsoft has decided for us that we need to explicitely type commit and rollback rather than click a button?  How thoughful of them! :(   I am not talking about "scripts", I'm working with simple ad-hoc queries that updates/inserts/deletes, and I don't want to type a command to do what a BUTTON can do easier.  And what is the point of having such extensible toolbars if they cant even include the most clicked button of Oracle's IDE?

Comment: If auto commit is off, the IDE will ask you about committing/discarding your changes, when you close the transaction window.

Comment: I came here wanting to ask the same question. I was surprised to have SQL server lock up behind a DDL statement which of course is unfathomable to any rational mind. I now understand why SQL server forces autocommit. It's better that a user has autocommit trash their database after a typo than have sqlserver look as bad as it is.

Comment: Another argument for having the button is that it seems dangerous to have random "commit" lines in your SQL file since you may accidentally execute the whole file in the editor window, in which case all of those random queries just had their changes committed.  Using a commit button instead of having to type and execute it would be safer in this context.

Answer (score 6):

In the SSMS IDE it's like autocommit is always on. I'm on the other end of this - I couldn't figure out why my record inserts weren't appearing in my new Oracle table!

Comment: Well if you're using Toad in Oracle and want your autocommit on to be like in SSMS default, then:  Options -> Oracle -> Transactions -> Commit after every statement.